# Getting this error while trying to communicate from servlet to jenkins: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/offbytwo/jenkins/JenkinsServer

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, servlets, jboss

I want to write a simple web-app with mvc-architecture. I use JBoss as a application-server so my frontend (view) are .jsp pages. My backend are simple java classes (model). I want to realize the communication between them with servlets. In the backend i want to implement a Jenkins-interface to get some data from different jenkins-jobs. When i run one of my java classes in the backend I get response from Jenkins as a xml-File, but when I want to trigger the same Method from my servlet I get this error

[see the Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1Fg6.png)

I commented the hole code out instead of following line:

JenkinsServer jenkins = new JenkinsServer(new URI("http://localhost:8080"), "username", "password");

my pom.xml looks like this

```
<groupId></groupId>
<artifactId>myWebApp</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.offbytwo.jenkins</groupId>
        <artifactId>jenkins-client</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I tried:

- clean, install my maven project
- changed the java version from 11 to 8
- i checkted if my jenkins was up to date and the java settings
- i deleted the .m2/repository folder
- i checked the version of the com.offbytwo.jenkins dependency

At the moment I am very helpless and I hope that anyone can help, why I can comunicate local with Jenkins, but not through my Aplication Server